# Python: traceback when using the lxml

Tags: python, lxml

code:

```
response = urllib2.urlopen('xxxxxxwebsite address')
html = response.read()
tree = etree.fromstring(html)
nodes = tree.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'badge-info')")
for node in nodes:
    print(node.text)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "extract1.py", line 11, in <module>
    tree = etree.fromstring(html)
  File "src\lxml\etree.pyx", line 3222, in lxml.etree.fromstring
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1877, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1765, in lxml.etree._parseDoc
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1127, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDoc
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 601, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 711, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 640, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError
  File "<string>", line 42
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Opening and ending tag mismatch: meta line 24 and head, line 42, column 8
```

Plesae suggest me if there is a better way than lxml to read.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo:

```
tree.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'badge-info')]")
#                                               ^ unclosed
```

Comment: Thanks for response. even after adding the missing unclose parameter I m getting the same error

Comment: @MLlearner Oh the exception is raised at `etree.fromstring`! Your raw HTML is broken. `lxml` cannot parse.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML isn't well-formed XML so you'll either have to use [`HTMLParser()`](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.HTMLParser-class.html) or [`HTML()`](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html#HTML) so that lxml can recover.

See "[Parsing HTML](https://lxml.de/parsing.html#parsing-html)" for more info.